# error: non-static method PostFixConverter(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static-methods, non-static

I'm doing some hw and am currently stumped. 
It gives an interface and a class for ArrayStack and asks to write a code that converts infix to postfix. 
In my main method is this line

```
PostFixConverter(infixExpression);
```

which calls to a method that calculates the postfix expression. 
My problem is that the class ArrayStack is not static but my main method is, so how can I resolve this?

Also,

Am I converting infix to postfix wrong by not making a new class that calculates postfix because all other code I've seen that does this has a separate class for it? Is there an advantage to doing it that way?

Thank You!

Comment: either make the method static or create instance of class and then call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first query refer below:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String infixExpression = "Your infix string";
    PostFixConverter(infixExpression);  
}

private static void PostFixConverter(String infixExpression) 
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

For second query, it's your choice to do it that way.

Comment: changed method to       
   private static void PostFixConverter(String infixExpression){
    and it now compiles!Thank You!  However new problems have arisen.

Comment: please share the issue.

Comment: My program is suppose to read from a file that has infix expressions, print them out, convert to postfix and print that out.                                          Output Example:                                                                                            Infix expression   = ((9/3)-2)
Postfix expression = 93/2-                                                                                     The file reading is good. However when I run my program it prints out the infix expression and just keeps running. Nothing else happens. Would it help is I made question about it?

Comment: you can add new question with code snippet.

Comment: Fixed the running thing by adding else's to some if's. If I am stuck again I shall ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create Object of your class in main method like following and call non static(instance method)

```
ArrayStack arrayStack = new ArrayStack();                                        
arrayStack.postFixConverter(infixExpression);
```